# Drupal form ajax and select stylization?

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to make ajax select, but I'm using selectBox for form and I'm not doing click on form element. How can I done this?

```
$form['choice_wrapper']['format'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('custom-text')),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'webform_technic_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-choice-wrapper',
        'method' => 'after',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        'event' => 'change',
      ),
    );
```

Sctipt for selectBox:

```
jQuery("select.custom-text").each(function() {                  
                    var sb = new SelectBox({
                        selectbox: jQuery(this),
                        height: 150,
                        // width: 340
                    });
                });
```

And I have this code:

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="webform-technic-form" method="post" action="/moy-ofis/moi-produkty/produkt-359-208/tehnicheskie-harakteristiki"><div><div id="edit-choice-wrapper" class="field clearfix form-wrapper"><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-format">
     <div id="select-edit-format" class="customSelect">
<select name="format" id="edit-format" class="custom-text2 form-select ajax-processed">
<option value="video">Video</option>
<option value="audio">Audio</option>
</select><div class="selectValueWrap">
<div class="selectedValue">Video</div> <span class="caret"></span> </div>
<div class="selectList"><div class="selectListOuterWrap">
<div class="selectListInnerWrap"><div class="selectListTop"></div><dl style=""><dd class="itm-0  selected">Video</dd><dd class="itm-1 ">Audio</dd></dl><div class="selectListBottom"></div></div></div></div></div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```